# C++ Will all code inside a nested 'if' statement run, even if that changes the boolean value of the outside statement?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have a couple of `if` statements in my C++ code (one nested inside the other), and I want to be sure that they will run as I expect- the code is:

```
if(state == entry){
    if(abs(distance < 0.05){
        state = arcing;
        ...
        startAngle = positionAC;
    }
    // Some more statements here...
}
```

If the second `if` statement condition is met, will the code where my comment "// Some more statements here..." be run now that the value of `state` has changed to `arcing` rather than `entry`? I would have thought that they should be run because the code will still be executing from when the first condition was true, even though it now no longer will be. Is this correct?

Comment: You could easily test this yourself.

Comment: Each statement is evaluated at most once in your code. Put a `std::cerr << "got here";` after the 2nd condition to see what happens.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: I don't get why the nested conditional is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The if-check

```
if(state == entry)
```

will be performed exactly once, at the moment that line is reached in the code.

From then on, it doesn't matter if the values of state or entry are modified - the entirety of the code inside the if-block will be executed, if state was equal to entry when that line was reached.

Comment: Brilliant, that's what I wanted to be sure of. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I remember once having this doubt about the Pascal `while` loop. The text book we had didn't describe the workings of the loop in very concrete terms, but only that it iterated “while” the condition was true. Some experimentation convinced me that the condition was only checked once per iteration, namely at the start of the loop. But the thing is, I should not have had to check that: the book should have been *clear* on that.

So, clarity:

A C++ `if` statement like

```
if( condition )
{
    action_1;
    action_2;
    action_3;
}
something_more;
```

is <sup>1</sup>equivalent to:

```
    const bool do_it = condition;    // The single evaluation of condition
    if( do_it ) goto do_actions;
    goto do_more_things;

do_actions:   // Just a name for this place in the code, a "label".
    action_1;
    action_2;
    action_3;          // The next executed statement is something_more.
do_more_things:
    something_more;
```

And yes, both are valid C++ code.

<sup><sup>1</sup>) This equivalence ignores possible name collisions, and it assumes that none of the actions are declarations. Declarations can foil the equivalence in two ways. First, it's not permitted to `goto`-jump over a declaration that executes initialization and that's in scope at the point jumped to. Second, destructors are executed when the execution leaves a block, and to capture that one has to imagine that those destructor executions are among the actions.</sup>

Comment: They're obviously not equivalent, since you have introduced `do_it` into scope, and the names of two labels; plus, if any of the actions are declarations, then those will prevent this code from compiling.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think (and thought) it would just be less obvious if I introduced double underscores everywhere. Better to write what people can readily understand. My take on it. ;-) The subtle details include not only name scopes and name collisions, but also in particular destructor actions. But showing the effect of a block as a block is not very illuminating.

Comment: I'll add that as a footnote.

Answer (score 0):

If the condition in the if statement

```
if(state == entry){
```

will be evaluated to `true` (it is evaluated only once in this point) then the compound statement of the if will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The statements under the comment will be executed exactly once, unless the first condition itself is NOT within a loop, or a method which is called recursively.

But if you want to make sure that the code after the comment is executed only when the state == entry at that point of time you can change your code as below

if((state == entry) && (abs(distance < 0.05)) {

```
state = arcing;

...

startAngle = positionAC;
```

}

else if (state == entry)

{

```
// Some more statements here...
```

}